# Why does Google Chrome not want to be my default browser?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Might sound like a silly question, but I notice that if I have IE set as my default browser and then open Fire Fox, Fire Fox wants to know if I want make it my default. If I say yes, then open Internet Explorer, IE wants to know if it can be the default browser. But, if I open chrome, it never asks to be the default browser.

Why do other browsers want to be the default choice, but Chrome does not?

Comment: Maybe it didn't like you.

Comment: Would you be running canary by any chance?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - nope. no canary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome does ask about it.
But each time it asks, there is an option "for not ask again", If you check that box chrome will not ask again.
To set chrome as your default browser

Comment: Hmm...I do not recall ever clicking for it not to ask.

Answer (score 2):

**Make Chrome your default browser**

If you like how Google Chrome works, make it your default browser! By doing so, future links you click will automatically open in Google Chrome.

Follow these steps to set Google Chrome as your default browser:

- Click the Chrome menu  on the browser toolbar.
- Select Settings.
- In the "Default browser" section, click Make Google Chrome my default browser.